# J2ME socket connection

Tags: sockets, java-me

I'm trying to implement a socket connection in my J2ME device. However I'm having some issues.

1- Sometimes the socket connection would just hang-up. I'd send a request, the server would get it and reply back but the response is never read by the client.

2- No timeout on socket: When the connection hangs, I'm forced to wait the whole 1 minute default timeout before I'm able to go out of the connection attempt. I've tried setting a timedTask to cancel/kill the thread executing the connection but I've had no success.

Any suggestions as to 1- why this could be happening (1) and how to properly implement a custom timeout for a j2me socket connection (2).

Thanks in advance,

Oscar

**SOCKET Connection**

```
String reply = "";
int ch;
try {
    String name = "socket://" + socketIp + ":" + socketPort;
    request = "request to socket";
    socket = (SocketConnection)Connector.open(name, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
    os = socket.openOutputStream();
    os.write(request.getBytes());
    is = socket.openInputStream();                
    while( true) {                           
        ch = is.read(); 
        if(ch == -1) break;
        if(ch < 0 && ch != -1){
            break;
        }
        reply += (char) ch;
        if(ch == '?'){
            break;
        }
    }
    socketReply(GlobalFunctions.Split(reply, "|"));                    
} catch (IOException ex){
    socketError("Error: " + ex);
} catch (NullPointerException ex){
    socketError("Error: " + ex);
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
    socketError("Error: " + ex);
} catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
    socketError("Error: " + ex);
} catch (Exception ex){
    socketError("Error: " + ex);
} finally {
    try {
        // Close open streams and the socket
        is.close();
        os.close();                
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

TIMED TASK (For custom timeOut)

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
    public final void run()
    {               
        try {
            renderBack(displayIndex); 
            errorDialog(0);            
            is.close();
            os.close();                
            socket.close();
            t.interrupt(); //Thread running the whole connection process
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
int timeOut = 20000;           
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timerTask, timeOut);
```

The timed task would work, meaning, it'd "execute" the timed tasks (at least the display change) but still the socket default timeout would be running because after 1 minute it'd throw me the "TimeOut" exception.

Comment: You need to post your code before anyone has a chance figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: @mr_lou I've edited my question.

Comment: How does your `socketReply()` function look like?
In which methods are the server code running? In a constructor? I can see the TimerTask stuff is running in a Thread - but I don't see when the server code is executed.

Comment: Hey @mr_lou, sorry I must have missed your comment notification. The socketReply() function simply receives a string and execute some processes depending on the string. I didn't think it was necessary to show that because the socket hangs before it even reaches the socketReply() function.